# Beam search in the context of Genetic Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, search-problem

As per *Machine Learning, Tom M. Mitchell*, Indian Edition, pp. 249-262, it is mentioned that "genetic algorithms employ a randomized beam search method to seek a maximally fit hypothesis".

I have searched Wikipedia for the term **beam search**. I could understand that it is a variation of the breadth-first search method. I couldn't relate it to the concepts mentioned in the chapter of GA in the said book.

Please explain what is the beam search method in the context of GAs?